# webscraping, span==0, extract text lines from 'span'==0

Tags: web, screen-scraping

how can I extract the "span" text in 4th row?
the site address: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVEMdqbwWTo
for inspection of element picture as below:
[image]
my for loop:
videos = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="description"]/yt-formatted-string')

time.sleep(3)

video_list = []

for video in videos:

Title = page_url #video.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/h1').text
Todayeng = video.find_element_by_tag_name('span').text
please help the "Todayeng" from 'span' red text.
"Title" is OK
but "Todayeng" output is empty....

Comment: Do you want to extract this text only for this exact case? Or you want to do something which will be valid for all videos.

Comment: thanks for your comment. i just extract this text only through for loop csv which was saved all video web link.